# Pandas: percentage of a value relative to the total of the group

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with sales quantity for a list of products. Each product is assigned a design/range name. Within each design, there may be multiple products. How can I perform calculations within only a certain design to find the sales split? I want to find out what percentage of a given range come from a certain product. I have so far only been able to take the entire list of products and calculate the percentage each contributes to the overall sales quantity.

Original datafram:

```
id  Product  Range  Quantity
1   Prod1      A    6        
2   Prod2      A    4         
3   Prod3      B    2         
4   Prod4      B    8
```

Dataframe after calculation:

```
id  Product  Range  Quantity  % of range
1   Prod1      A    6             60%
2   Prod2      A    4             40%
3   Prod3      B    2             20%
4   Prod4      B    8             80%
```

Comment: you should provide a clear input and matching expected output. Likely what you want is a simple `groupby.agg`, make sure to check the similar questions first

Comment: thanks, I have edited the original question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a simple `groupby.transform('sum')` to get the total per group, then perform classical vector arithmetic.

I provided an example as float and one as string:

```
total = df.groupby('Range')['Quantity'].transform('sum')

# as float
df['% of range'] = df['Quantity'].div(total)

# as string
df['% of range (str)'] = df['Quantity'].div(total).mul(100).astype(int).astype(str) + ' %'
```

output:

```
   id Product Range  Quantity  % of range % of range (str)
0   1   Prod1     A         6         0.6             60 %
1   2   Prod2     A         4         0.4             40 %
2   3   Prod3     B         2         0.2             20 %
3   4   Prod4     B         8         0.8             80 %
```

Comment: I didn't know about groupby's `.transform`, this is quite clearly a better solution.

Comment: this is perfect and does exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, appreciate it. Did not know about the .transform

Answer (score 3):

Edit: You should see [mozway's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71857434/12932966), because mine is basically doing the same thing in more steps ; I didn't know about [`.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) which does in a single, straight-forward line what I'm doing in 2.

To select only lines wich satisfy a particular condition (e.g. have a value of `Product` equal to `Prod1`) :

```py
df[df.Product == "Prod1]
```

Thus to get the sum of the quantity for prod1 regardless of the Range, you would do :

```py
df[df.Product == "Prod1"]["Quantity"].sum()
```

If you want to do the same for every value, use [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) :

```py
sum_per_range = df[["Range", "Quantity"]].groupby("Range").sum()
```

Gives you the total quantity per Range, now we need to create a new column that will use these values :

```py
df["%"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.Quantity/sum_per_range[x.Range],
                   axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks - what I am trying to do is perform a calculation on rows with id = 1 and id = 2 and store the results in '% of range' column as these products correspond to the same range. Then, I want to do the same calculation on row  with id = 3 and id = 4 and so on. So that I end up with a column that adds up to 100% for EACH range.

Comment: thanks for this. Can confirm it works, but as per your suggestion, have gone with @mozway solution in the end.